# Логика прототипов в Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

В популярном учебнике learn.javascript.ru в уроке о прототипах есть один хороший пример:

```
let animal = {
  eats: true
};

function Rabbit(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Rabbit.prototype = animal;
```

И казалось бы все нормально, есть Животное и Кролик который наследует от него свойства через `Rabbit.prototype`, прослеживается логичная иерархия. Свойства же самого Кролика у нас создаются с помощью конструктора Rabbit.

Но почему в встроенных конструкторах используется немного другая логика, менее очевидная.
Например при создании `const arr = new Array()` свои свойства и методы специфичные для массива мы получаем из `Array.prototype`, а не из самого `Array`. По аналогии с кроликом, из `Array.prototype` мы должны получить свойства и методы иерархией выше, т.е свойства объектов.

Понимаю что в данном случае это нужно чтобы "скрыть" встроенные свойства, и отделить от тех которые добавляем мы. Но пока я все еще в замешательстве...

Comment: А раздел про наследование уже читал? Пример так себе, в последнем абзаце вообще всё неверно.

Comment: логика та же самая - поля, которые свои у каждого отдельного объекта, определяются в конструкторе, функции, которые одинаковые у всех объектов - в прототипе

Comment: @Qwertiy жду хотя бы уточнения, что именно неверно в последнем абзаце

Comment: @Flpae, в последнем абзаце полностью неверное предположение.

Comment: @Grundy окей, но раз уж мы на stackoverflow, но давайте говорить "почему" неверное, а не просто тыкать в это пальцем, думаю так будет лучше

Comment: @Flpae, потому что встроенные свойства **НЕ** скрываются и никак не отделяются от тех, которые добавляем мы.

Answer (score 2):

В примере скорее всего хотели продемонстрировать, что "так работает".

> По аналогии с кроликом, из Array.prototype мы должны получить свойства и методы иерархией выше, т.е свойства объектов

А где в этом примере "иерархией выше"? `animal` - просто объект, который прямо записывается в прототип кролика.

Когда из объекта вызывается метод:

1. JS cперва проверит наличие этого метода среди свойств объекта. Если его там нет,
2. Будет искать метод в `.prototype` функции-конструктора, с помощью которого был создан этот объект. Соответственно, у созданного объекта есть внутреннее свойство `.__proto__` которое ссылается на `.prototype` своего конструктора. Не путать __proto__ и prototype: Первое - внутри созданных объектов, второе - свойство функции-конструктора.
3. Если и здесь его не будет... `.prototype` - сам является объектом, у которого тоже может быть `.__proto__` - попробует поискать там, и т.д.

---

Касаемо Array.prototype...

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
  
console.log( arr.hasOwnProperty("0") ); // true
console.log( arr.hasOwnProperty("4") ); // false
```

Что же произошло?

Хотим вызвать метод `hasOwnProperty()`

1. Есть ли внутри `arr` такой? Нет, там только свойства `"0", "1", "2"` которые соответственно хранят значения `"a", "b", "c"` (и свойство `length: 3`)
2. Идет к `arr.__proto__` оно же, `Array.prototype`

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log( arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype ); // true;
```

Можно вызвать `console.log( Array.prototype )` и убедиться, что там тоже нет метода `hasOwnProperty()`

[image]

Но есть `.__proto__` который тоже ссылается на некий объект

[image]

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log( arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype)
console.log( Array.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype) // true
console.log( arr.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype ) // true
```

И о чудо, находится hasOwnProperty(), который в итоге вызывается в контексте `arr`.

[image]

---

Это можно представить в виде здания. Ищу метод:

1. Проверил у себя - не нашел,
2. Зашел на первый этаж (моя функция-конструктор), открыл дверь (`prototype`), не нашел метод в комнате,
3. Через лестницу (`__proto__`) поднялся на следующий этаж. Открыл дверь там (`prototype` конструктора, от которого наследуем), и т.п.
4. Если дошел до крыши, так ничего и не нашел - выдам ошибку `... is not a function`

Comment: Rabbit вполне себе наследуется от animal - в этом и суть **прототипного** наследования.

Comment: `Rabbit.prototype = Animal.prototype;` так не надо делать, иначе при добавлении метода в прототип Rabbit он добавится и в прототип Animal

Comment: @Grundy Однако, спасибо) До сих пор, оказывается, путался в терминах.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME 

`// Все функции создаются один раз и спокойно лежат в прототипе.`
Вот речь как раз об этом. Вопрос не в том, что методы будут создаваться заново (неизвестно как движок это обрабатывает), а в том что в Rabbit.prototype по моей логике должен находиться прототип кролика - т.е Animal, а не сами методы и свойства для Rabbit.

Comment: "Прототип кролика" в данном случае не как концепция языка JS, а как формальное описание чего-то, что выше по иерархии

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, _Чтобы этого не случалось, вместо присваивания пишут или Object.assign(Rabbit.prototype, Animal.prototype)_ неправда :-) пишут `Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`

Comment: В общем первый пример кода и последующий абзац надо либо переписать, либо убрать - он плохой

Comment: @Flpae Переписал ответ*

Comment: @Grundy Что-то меня и правда не туда занесло. Весь пример был лишним, ничего толком не демонстрировал. Переписал. И спасибо!)